# SharePoint search service setup with desired state configuration error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, dsc

I'm configuring a SharePoint 2013 deployment using Desired State Configuration (DSC). I have configured several services to be provisioned using DSC, but I am having trouble getting search config to work. The following command fails in the context of DSC, but works fine when running with the exact same parameters in a normal PowerShell window:

```
function Set-TargetResource
{
...        
$searchApp = New-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Name $searchAppName `
        -DatabaseServer $dbServer `
            -DatabaseName $searchDB `
            -ApplicationPool $pool `
            -AdminApplicationPool $adminPool `
            -Partitioned:([bool]::Parse($partitioned))
    If (!$?) {
        Throw "  - An error occurred creating the $searchAppName application."
    }
...
```

Other SharePoint cmdlets are working fine from within DSC. I know DSC runs in the context of "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" - is this causing the problem for some SharePoint PowerShell cmdlets? - if so, how could search configuration still be achieved within the context of DSC?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use different set of credentials that got the SP farm access. See [xWindowsProcess DSC resource](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/xPSDesiredStateConfiguratio-417dc71d) for an example. This is available as a part of the DSC resource kit.